# Error while deploying Azure resource template from Github through Visual Studio

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine

While deploying the template through Visual Studio, I am getting an error.

VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'dscExtension'. Error message:

> The DSC Extension failed to execute: Error downloading
>   https://stagef848a9a999ac4175a5c.blob.core.windows.net/myresourcegroup-stageartifactsscripts/WebServerConfig.ps1.zip
>   after 2 attempts: `AuthenticationFailed`Server
>   failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
>   13:58:38 - RequestId:d731468a-601e-00be-15ea-b36a90000000 13:58:38 -
>   Time:2018-03-04T18:58:06.8482865ZSignature did not match. String to sign used was r

When I looked for a solution, somebody suggested to append 
`&comp=list&restype=container` to artifacts location. I tried but failed.

What is the exact location in JSON (Specific parameter) where I should add this string?

Comment: Can you provide more information? You mentioned this is from GitHub so providing a link to the template would be good.

Comment: Here is the Github template link - https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/iis-2vm-sql-1vm

Comment: Hi, Any help on this please.  Searching for the answer for a long time. Appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 0):

> The DSC Extension failed to execute: Error downloading https://stagef848a9a999ac4175a5c.blob.core.windows.net/myresourcegroup-stageartifactsscripts/WebServerConfig.ps1.zip after 2 attempts: AuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request.

According to your error message, it seems that your supplied blob [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1) for downloading the blob is invaild. You could try to download the blob with blob SAS token url directly to check it. If it is invaild we could generate blob SAS token with [azure portal](https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2017/01/11/azure-storage-account-configure-security-using-shared-access-signature/) or [Azure Storage explorer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/10/12/easily-create-a-sas-to-download-a-file-from-azure-storage-using-azure-storage-explorer/) eas.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing the link. I looked at the link that explained how to create a SAS Token. So Is it must to have storage account created already and SAS Token to deploy the template? What if I have to  generate the storageaccount dynamically? How to handle SAS token creation? Please help me.

Comment: I also tried deploying the github template (https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/dsc-extension-iis-server-windows-vm) from visual studio. It is giving an error "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'dscExtension'. Error message: "The DSC Extension failed to execute: Error downloading http://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/raw/master/dsc-extension-iis-server-windows-vm/ContosoWebsite.ps1.zip after 29 attempts: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.." though I changed the protocol from https to http. Please help.

Comment: Hi, Any help on this please.  Searching for the answer for a long time. Appreciate your help very much.

Comment: @SureshBabu If I have free time  I will look into [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/dsc-extension-iis-server-windows-vm) that you shared. And if any update I will add the comment here.